# JTable not updating itself

Tags: java, swing, jtable, refresh, repaint

I want my jtable update itself when i pick a table from database in combobox. But nothing happens and program gives array index out of bounds exception. I used `repaint()` and `revalidate()` functions but i couldn't find a solution.

**EDIT:** I have now null pointer exception at right here: `table.setModel(tableModel);`

```
   public class DBC extends JFrame{

    static String tablo;
    static JTextField tf = new JTextField(20);
    static int columnCount;
    static JPanel tfPanel = new JPanel();
    static String[] sutunlar;
    static JLabel sutunLabel;
    static JPanel sutunPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    static JTable table;
    static JScrollPane scrollPane;
    static DefaultTableModel tableModel;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project"
                  ,"root","123456789");

        final Statement statement = connect.createStatement();

        JLabel tabloSec = new JLabel("Tablo Seçin:");
        final JComboBox<String> tablolar = new JComboBox<String>();
        final DatabaseMetaData md = connect.getMetaData();
        final ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);

        while (rs.next()) {
            tablolar.addItem(rs.getString(3));
        }

        tablolar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                tablo = tablolar.getSelectedItem().toString();

                try {

                     ResultSet rs2 = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+tablo);
                     ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs2.getMetaData();
                     columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

                     sutunlar = new String[columnCount];

                     Object columnNames[] = new Object[columnCount];
                     Object rowData[][] = {{""}};
                     tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);

                         for(int i=0;i<columnCount;i++){

                             sutunlar[i] = rsmd.getColumnLabel(i+1);
                             columnNames[i] = sutunlar[i];

                             }

                         tableModel.addRow(rowData);
                         tableModel.addColumn(columnNames);
                         table.setModel(tableModel);
                         table.repaint();
                         scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
                         sutunPanel.add(scrollPane);
                         sutunPanel.revalidate();
                         sutunPanel.repaint();


                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        JButton ekle = new JButton("Ekle");
        ekle.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                try {
                    switch(tablo){
                    case "department":

                        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO department(Name,Location) VALUES('"+tf.getText()+"')");
                    case "employee":

                        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO employee(Id,FirstName,LastName,Sex,Address,Email,Salary,BirthDate,JoinDate) VALUES('"+tf.getText()+"')");
                    case "engineer":

                        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO engineer(EngineerType) VALUES('"+tf.getText()+"')");
                    case "manager":

                        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO manager(Department) VALUES('"+tf.getText()+"')");
                    case "project":

                        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO project(Name,Number,Value) VALUES('"+tf.getText()+"')");
                    case "secretary":

                        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO secretary(TypingSpeed) VALUES('"+tf.getText()+"')");
                    }

                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        JButton cik = new JButton("Çık");
        cik.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        panel.add(tabloSec);
        panel.add(tablolar);
        panel.add(sutunPanel);
        panel.revalidate();
        panel.add(ekle);
        panel.add(cik);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Deneme");
        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Missing `break;` at end of case with SQL INSERT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not replace the `JTable`

```
table = new JTable(1,columnCount);
```

Instead, update the existing `TableModel` or create a new `TableModel` and use `JTable#setModel` to replace the model.

Comment: Ok i used table model but now i have null pointer exception. I edited my post.

Comment: @Miral The first time you need to create a new `JTable`. Only afterwards, you can call `setModel`. That explains your `NullPointerException`

Comment: Ok robin thanks. But is it normal for my code to create a table with 4 columns and 3 rows. I only wanted with 2 columns and 1 row for that specific database table and the first 2 columns come with A and B names.

Answer (score 1):

> But nothing happens and program gives array index out of bounds exception.

Don't use Arrays since you don't know the amount of data that will be returned from the SQL query.

You should use a Vector for the columns names. You will also need a second Vector for the Data. Finally for each row returned you need a new Vector which you add to the data Vector.

Currently your code doesn't even attempt to get the data from the ResultSet. You are only getting the columns names which is not very useful.

Once you get all the data you create a new DefaultTableModel using the columnName Vector and the data Vector. Then you use the table.setModel() method to update your table.

Answer (score 0):

try adding SwingUtilities.invokeLater() after you get the data back from your database. Its probably an Event Dispatch Problem. Also, don't construct your GUI components in the actionListener() (Thats bound to cause problems)

Comment: invokeLater() is not needed since all the code is being executed on the EDT. However, it is not a good idea to execute all the code on the EDT since this will make the GUI unresponsive while the database call is executing. Instead take a look at using a SwingWorker.